# Why is the integral zero

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Following setup: $u \in C^{\infty}([0,T] \times \mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^N)$, $A^i \in C^{\infty}([0,T] \times \mathbb{R}^n, Mat_N(\mathbb{R}))$, $A^i$ symmetric, bounded, $i=1,...,n$.

Also, $u$ is bounded in the following way (Schwartz bound): Let $\alpha, \beta$ be multiindices. Then there exists a constant $C_{\alpha, \beta}$, s.t.

$\vert x^{\alpha} \vert ( \vert \partial^{\beta} u \vert+ \vert \partial^{\beta} \partial_0 u \vert) (t,x) \leq C_{\alpha \beta}$

Is it then true, that

$\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n} \partial_i(u^T A^i u) dx =0$

I've seen it in a computation but I don't see why this is true.

Comment: I don't see why it has to be integrable.  Just let $N=1$, $A^i=1$, and $u\to\infty$ sufficiently quickly.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot something, I will edit